# Can you transit through the Philippines on an emergency travel document issued by Malaysia?

Tags: transit, philippines, malaysian-citizens

Can I transit in another country before returning to my home country using an emergency travel document? I'm a Malaysian currently in Japan. I lost my passport and I'm currently being issued an emergency travel document. The problem here is that I have to transit through the Philippines before returning to Malaysia. Will there be any problems during my transit?

Comment: Are you just changing planes or do you need to go through Philippine immigration?

Answer (score 1):

No, you would not need a visa for your connection, according to Timatic, the tool used by airlines to check document requirements. Your emergency passport document issued by Malaysia is accepted for entry into The Philippines (whether transit or maximum stay of 30 days).